# How to penalize change of states in Hidden Markov model?

Tags: regularization, hidden-markov-model, constraint

I'm trying to fit a HMM on a sequence of observations and I would like to introduce some constraints that would penalize an excessive number of changes of state in the complete sequence (where "change" here means going from state Si to Sj, i<>j). It's like if changing from one state to another costs something. I would like this cost be taken in account when calculating the likeliest sequence of states given sequence of observations. Moreover, some states are more expensive than others (going from Si to Sk costs more than going from Si to Sj).

Any clue on how to introduce this sort of constraints in a HMM? If not possible, what kind of models could be used instead?

Comment: put suitable priors on the transition matrix

Comment: @Taylor in terms of transition probabilities, I suppose it means that these probabilities (ex: going from Si to Sj) should change in time to reflect the fact that going from Sk to Sl somewhere in the past has some associated cost. I don't think priors on the transition matrix can model that, am I wrong?

Comment: Then they become part of the state. That’s fine too. And no you’re not wrong: priors won’t make parameters move.

Comment: @Taylor sorry but I don't understand what you mean by "they become part of the state"

Comment: Anything that moves and is unobserved has to be a state variable. If it were me, the first thing I’d try is make the logit of the probability evolve on the reals. That might be difficult if you’re restricting yourself to finite state spaces, though.

Comment: @Taylor Are you saying that HMM are not well adapted for this constraint and if yes, are there in your opinion any other models that could be considered?